# Why is the result NULL? (PHP)

Tags: php, function, null

Why is the result of `$d` `NULL`?

```
<?php
 function aduna($a,$b){    
$d=$a+$b;}
 $d=aduna(2,3);
var_dump($d);
?>
```

Comment: You must return $d in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return value.

```
 function aduna($a,$b)
 {    
 return $d=$a+$b;
 }
 $d=aduna(2,3);
 var_dump($d);
```

Answer (score 1):

`aduna` doesn't return anything explicitly, so it implicitly returns `NULL`. Just return the result and you should be OK:

```
function aduna($a,$b) {
    return $a + $b; # Here!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way

```
<?php
function aduna($a,$b){    
    return $a+$b;
}

$d=aduna(2,3);
var_dump($d);
```